# Deriving the maximum likelihood for a generative classification model for K classes

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

In Christopher Bishop's book "Pattern Recognition and Machine learning", there is the following question:

> Consider a generative classification model for $K$ classes defined by the prior class probabilities $p(C_k) = \pi_k$ and general class-conditional densities $p(\phi|C_k)$ where $\phi$ is the input feature vector ... show that the maximum-likelihood solution for the prior probabilities is given by:
>
> $$
> \pi_k = \frac{N_k}{N}
> $$

where $N_k$ is the number of data points assigned to class $C_k$ and $\textbf{t}_n$ is a binary target vector of length $K$ which uses the 1-of-$K$ coding scheme.

While reviewing the solution (4.9, freely available here: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/pdf/prml-web-sol-2009-09-08.pdf) I was particularly stuck at a certain step. So first, we obtain the log-likelihood, given by:

$$
\ln p(\{\phi_n, \textbf{t}_n\}\lvert\{\pi_k\}) = \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^K t_{nk} \{\ln p(\phi_n \lvert \textbf{C}_k) + \ln \pi_k \} \tag1
$$

Then, in order to maximise the likelihood, we need to preserve the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_k = 1$, so we introduce a Lagrange multiplier as follows:

$$
\ln p(\{\phi_n, \textbf{t}_n\}\lvert\{\pi_k\}) + \lambda \bigg( \sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_k - 1 \bigg) \tag 2
$$

Then, in order to obtain the maximum likelihood, we need to differentiate the log likelihood with respect to $\pi_k$ and set the derivative to $0$, giving us:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{t_{nk}}{\pi_k} + \lambda = 0 \tag 3
$$

And here is where I get lost, since my own derivation of the derivative of equation $2$ does not result in eliminating the summations over K. In fact, what I get is the following:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{t_{nk}}{\pi_k} + \lambda k = 0 \tag 4
$$

What exactly am I missing?

Comment: You are calculating derivative incorrectly. Variables $\pi_k$ are different, so differentiating w.r.t. $\pi_k$ you should get $\pi_i' = 0$ for all $i \neq k$ and the summation over $k$ disappears.

Comment: @psarka Ahaa ! So when taking the derivative with respect to $\pi_k$ i am specifying a particular class, as opposed to the variable $\pi$ indexed by k (i.e. the prior probability of each class) am I right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. :)

Comment: Well, your question helped us find the answer, so I thought sharing what we found might help you. See Q8: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/189/exam/mids14.pdf It has a more descriptive solution for the same question.

Comment: Am i right in thinking that this is the same as finding the MLE for a multinomial random variable ? @psarka

Comment: @XavierBourretSicotte Yes, you are right: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421105/maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-parameters-of-multinomial-distribution